# laravel iterate through @foreach using numerical keys

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, mailgun

I been stuck on this problem for a day now.

Been passing data to views like this:

```
return view('email') -> with ('name', $results);
```

This is what $results looks like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#204 ▶}
  1 => {#205 ▼
    +"Field": "Art Education"
    +"Authors": "Genos"
    +"Title": "Modern Art"
    +"Date": "2015"
    +"Adviser": "Saitama"
    +"Language": "English"
    +"Subject": "Test Case"
  }
]
```

The view then receives it like this:

```
@foreach ($name as $name)
//
@endforeach
```

This works great, but now im working with Mailgun.

And this is how $results must be passed

```
Mail::send('email', $results, function($message) {

    $message->to('email@example.com', 'Your Friendly Neighborhood Spiderman')->subject('Your Cart');

    });
```

The main difference is in mailgun, I cannot use the `with ('name', $results)` clause in the second argument so I am stuck with an associative array where each key is an iterating number (example: 1, 2, 3... etc.)

Is there any way for me to iterate through $results in blade with @foreach if its keys were numbers?

Apparently I can no longer work with `@foreach ($name as $name)`

Thanks!

Comment: why you cannot work @foreach in blade? It should perfectly work.

Comment: Ah, because the second argument in Mail:send won't allow me to define a variable that I can pass each object in $results to. I cannot use Mail::send('email', ('name', $results), function($message). So there is no 'name' in @foreach for me to pass each object to in the loop.

Comment: Once you pass $results you can access that array inside your email.blade.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me

```
$data['results'] = $results;

Mail::send('email', $data, function($message) {

$message->to('email@example.com', 'Your Friendly Neighborhood Spiderman')->subject('Your Cart');

});
```

and in mail.blade.php i can iterate

```
@foreach ($results as $name)
```

Comment: Let me try what you did. What you did differently was the: $data['results'] = $results; part. This passed my results into an array key I can catch in the view. You made it look so simple. I hope it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: You have solved my problem. Thank you so much and take my upvote. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass your $results to Mail::send function you can access this data in your email blade template just like any other blade file.